# BITCOIN MINING POOL OPERATION CONCERN

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability, mining-reward

I have contributed Bitcoin into a mining pool that was being promoted on Instagram.  The miner of the pool informed me that the process consists of 5 cycles.  He set an initial amount of Bitcoin to be submitted into the pool, and then decreased the amount for next 4 cycles.  After the 5th cycle was completed, the I received "Non-Spendable" funds in my Blockchain wallet, which I cannot touch and that will not show up on my dashboard.  I informed the miner of the situation and he told me that I have to submit an activation fee of .2 BTC in order for the funds to be released into my wallet.  The miner then informed me again that I will be able to take back the .2 BTC after the funds are released into my wallet and that this function is how the mining machine works.  Is this fraud?

Comment: Yes, this is 100% fraud. You can try to find help from local authorities. If you're in the US, this [page](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/blog/2019/11/scams-telling-you-pay-bitcoin-rise) suggests  https://ftc.gov/complaint

Comment: I transferred Bitcoin from my Coinbase platform to the Blockchain platform to complete the transaction with the scammer.  Is my Coinbase account compromised?

Comment: Did you give any private keys to the scammer? Otherwise, no.

Comment: No.  The only thing that I did was hold my Coinbase barcode up to the computer barcode for Blockchain.

Comment: What you have described is absolutely NOT how bitcoin mining works. This is most definitely a scam, sorry for your loss.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this fraud?

Yes. Essentially you gave money to a stranger you've never met who told you a story that seemed plausible but was a pack of lies.

Typical indications of scam

- unspendable funds
- activation fee
- false description of how mining works
- promoted on social media (private messaging)